# How to set client_name sessionid in pandorabot. AIML

Tags: bots, aiml, pandorabots

How to set client_name sessionid in pandorabot AIML.
Or is there any way I can get them from my web. I am using chat widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some docs explaining this here: https://pandorabots.com/docs/api-endpoints/#talk-to-bot-public
Basically though, you just append them to your talk request.

...talk?botkey=XXXXX&input=Hello&client_name=widgetcustomer&sessionid=123